# Equivalent of #region for C++

Tags: c#, c++

What's the C++ equivalent of #region for C++ so I can put in custom code collapsible bits and make my code a little easier to read?

Comment: This is a feature of the IDE rather than the language, isn't it?

Comment: @BjörnPollex, it's used by the IDE but it shouldn't conflict with the language syntax and the compiler must accept it as well.

Comment: `#region`, as far as C# goes, is valid syntax and delineates a region of code. Visual Studio allows you to fold them, as an IDE feature.

Comment: you can't use #region to make your code easier to read, #region makes you code easier to *not* read.

Comment: I suggest a line comment followed by a block statement.

Comment: Just using #pragma region and #pragma endregion: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/region-endregion?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The Region keyword is IDE specific and affects rendering in Visual Studio. The nearest equivalent is [#pragma Region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/region-endregion?view=msvc-170) which is applicable to Visual Studio only .

Code example from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/region-endregion?view=msvc-170)

```
// pragma_directives_region.cpp
#pragma region Region_1
void Test() {}
void Test2() {}
void Test3() {}
#pragma endregion Region_1

int main() {}
```

Comment: if it's only IDE specific should I worry about compiling a code with `#pragma region`? Is there any C compiler which denies it? Is there any consequence at all? Thanks

Comment: Just checked using `Mingw`.  Using `gcc -Wall`, shows warnings about unknown pragmas. Like:  `warning: ignoring #pragma region test [-Wunknown-pragmas]` and `warning: ignoring #pragma endregion [-Wunknown-pragmas]`

Answer (score 34):

In addition to `#pragma region`…`#pragma endregion` for Visual Studio, many IDEs support the following syntax for regions in any `{}`-delimited, `//`-commented language:

```
//{ Region header text.
…
//}
```

Notable examples include [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) and [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/), and any other editor that uses the [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/) editing component, such as [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), [Geany](http://www.geany.org/), [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit), and many more.

Comment: Does VS support this?

Comment: Just tried, it doesn't (Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition)

Comment: I would suggest adding the header before the opening brace so that when it's collapsed you'll still be able to see the name (in more compilers at least).

Answer (score 13):

There isn't an equivalent in C++. However IDEs should be able to collapse sections.

It is also possible to use something like this:

```
#pragma region

#pragma endregion A comment about the region.
```

But probably not very portable

Answer (score 11):

I've been using

```
#ifndef ANY_NAME_FOR_THIS_REGION
    ...
#endif
```

for several projects during the last couple of years and that suits me (including collapsible blocks). as an addition, i can disable the block using #define ANY_NAME_FOR_THIS_REGION just above it.

Comment: #if 1 is even simpler than #ifndef, but.. it doesnt enforce the use of a symbol to describe the purpose of that region (the name following #ifndef) - I know you can prepend or append a comment to "#if 1", but it's not managed by the IDE. To be honest, i still use "#if 1..else..endif" just when i need to execute just one of two blocks of code (one block XOR the other)

Answer (score 10):

There is no equivalent. The [`#region` feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek.aspx) is part of the C# specification.

C++  has no such equivalent. You could possibly mimic it with specially formatted comments, but this would be editor specific.

For Visual Studio you can use:

```
#pragma region name
...
#pragma endregion name
```

Comment: So when you say *there is no such equivalent* you are wrong because `#pragma region` _is_, for all intents and purposes, its functional equivalent.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk - no, it isn't - not if you use any IDE that is not Visual Studio. `#region` is defined in the spec and IDEs that conform to the spec should allow collapsing regions - this can't be said for `#pragma region`.

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition to other answers. The region definition varies from IDE to IDE.

For Mac development in [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) you can use a pragma:

```
#pragma mark
```

Answer (score 1):

[C++Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2BBuilder) *does* support this, but you must declare the region as:

```
#pragma region BLAH

.....

#pragma end_region
```

You *must* use end_region for C++Builder, but it *will* work, and it *will* collapse the region!

Answer (score 1):

Kate, KDevelop and all other text editors and IDEs which use [Katepart](https://kate-editor.org/about-katepart/) supports marking regions with `//BEGIN` and `//END` markers.

```
// BEGIN GPT entity types
#define GPT_ENT_TYPE_UNUSED \
    {0x00000000,0x0000,0x0000,0x00,0x00,{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}}
#define GPT_ENT_TYPE_EFI \
    {0xc12a7328,0xf81f,0x11d2,0xba,0x4b,{0x00,0xa0,0xc9,0x3e,0xc9,0x3b}}
#define GPT_ENT_TYPE_MBR \
    {0x024dee41,0x33e7,0x11d3,0x9d,0x69,{0x00,0x08,0xc7,0x81,0xf3,0x9f}}
// END
```

You will be able to collapse a region defined in such way.

Answer (score 1):

I use multiple blocks of namespace'd code with the same namespace. The IDE let's me collapse by namespace block, so I just see the code of single block I'm working on e.g.

```
namespace MyNamespace{ // Quantise utility
  int Quantise1() { ...}
  float Quantise2() { ...}
} // MyNamespace Quantise utility
namespace MyNamespace{ // ADC utility
  int ADC1() { ...}
  float ADC2() { ...}
} // MyNamespace ADC utility
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no equivalent.

Most good editors or IDEs will let you collapse functions, if not also `if`/`else`/`while`/`for`/etc.

Answer (score -2):

The first answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21004631/about-collapsing-code-block-in-visual-studio-using-pragma-region) mentions another alternative. It is not applicable in all situations, though.

**Method:** Use {...} instead which natively supports code collapsing in Visual Studio.

1. Enable option: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting -> OutLine Statement Blocks -> True.
2. Put your in different scopes {...}, then it will collapse the code in different scopes:

[image: Scoped code collapsing example]

Comment: This might not work with all code as it will cause scoping issues for variables inside this block