# About collapsing code block in Visual Studio using #pragma region

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, pragma

In VisualStudio, when you write a function it can collapse to outlines, everyone knows it.  Also you can use `#pragma region` and `#pragma endregion` to manually specify a code region so that it can collapse. However I found a problem that, if any collapsed code blocks are within the `#pragma region`, they cannot collapse anymore. Is there any way to solve it?

[image: <code>funcA()</code>,<code>funcB()</code>, <code>funcC()</code> can be collapsed]

[image: After I add <code>#pragma region</code>, they cannot collapse independently.]

Comment: Are you using VS2010? This problem has apparently been fixed in VS2012.

Answer (score 9):

There are several other also better and flexible ways than `#pragma region` you can do to collapse code in VS:

**Method 1:** Use `{...}` instead which natively supports code collapsing in VS.

1. Enable option: `Tools->Text Editor->C/C++->Formatting->OutLine Statement Blocks->True`.
2. Put your in different scopes `{...}`, then it will collapse the code in different scopes:

   [image]

---

**Method 2:** use keyboard shortcuts to collapse code you want:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> will collapse all.
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> will expand all.
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> will expand all and disable outlining.
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> will collapse/expand the current section.

---

It is worthy noting that method #1 works better for plain code snippets. For functions, because similar to that [we cannot have functions inside functions in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324763/c-can-we-have-functions-inside-functions), we cannot put functions in scope defined by `{...}`. Fortunately, we can still use method #1 for functions by creating namespaces for each scope. Or simply, use method #2.

Comment: I was just wondering, how few functions can resides under { } ? Don't it screw other formatting?

Comment: @Digital_Reality This method works better for plain code snippets, not for functions, similar for that [we cannot have functions inside functions in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324763/c-can-we-have-functions-inside-functions). What do you mean by `screw other formatting`?

Comment: Well, OPs question was specific to functions inside his region. So I guess does not suits to his needs. But good to know, Thanks!

Comment: @Digital_Reality For functions, better to use method 2.

Comment: @Digital_Reality Updated by adding how to use method #1 for functions.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that problem exist

One workaround which sometimes works is to use outlining -> collapse to definitions, then re-expand each block.