# Prevent clang-format from removing emacs's formfeed character

Tags: emacs, clang-format

I use `clang-format` to format my source code. It's really handy, however, I'm facing an issue while working on Emacs. I separate my files into [pages](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/emacs/html_node/emacs_237.html) to keep them narrow, especially when dealing with large header files, this becomes really handy.

The thing is, in order to specify a page, you need to insert a special character `014` or `^L`, but `clang-format` removes this character everything time I format. Is there any way to alter this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought this was not possible. However, you can do it by enclosing the `^L` inside quotes. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    function_call_on_first_page();
    // "^L" <-- use an actual control-L character inside those quotes
    function_call_on_next_page();
    return 0;
}
```

It's ugly, but it might solve your problem. I tested this with clang-format version 6.0. Either single or double quotes seem to work.

Alternatively, you might try separating your code into "regions", and use one of the methods described at [Equivalent of #region for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000479/equivalent-of-region-for-c). Unfortunately, none of those methods are very portable.

Comment: Ah, it looks like emacs only uses ^L if it is alone on a line. Sorry, I don't see any solution then.

Comment: Yeah that's the case, I see if I can make some elisp hacking to make it work.. Thanks for your help nonetheless